# Intersection Observer API: How to find which element the user is observing

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer

I'm trying to create events each time that the user observes certain elements of the HTML code:

```
<div class="myunit no1">...</div>
<div class="myunit no2">...</div>
<div class="myunit no3">...</div>
```

I created the following JavaScript code:

```
const myElements = document.querySelectorAll('div.myunit');
const config = {rootMargin: '0px 0px 500px 0px'};
let observer = new IntersectionObserver(function (events, self) {
  events.forEach(event => {
    if (event.isIntersecting) {         
        console.log("Intersection");
    } 
  });
}, config);

myElements.forEach(myElement => {observer.observe(myElement);});
```

For each intersection, I would like to know which 'div' the user is observing. I'm just able to log the "Intersection".

I tried by analyzing the 'events' object, and I see it's an 'IntersectionObserverEntry', whose 'target' is, e.g., 'div.myunit.no2'. However, I do not know how to catch this 'div.myunit.no2' value.

'div.myunit.no2' is the value I get in Chrome DevTools Console if I include:

```
console.log('object: %O', events);
```

within the "let observer". This is, 'events' is an object which is Array(1). The first arrow promts a 'IntersectionObserverEntry', and then more arrows. One of the arrows in 'target', whose value is 'div.myunit.no2'.

If I scroll down, I get 'div.myunit.no3' in the Chrome Console, and if I scroll up back, I get 'div.myunit.no3'. I wondered how can I catch this value that I'm able to get only in Chrome Console within my JavaScript code.

Comment: What do you mean by catching the `div.myunit.no2` value ? You can simply keep adding them to an array or if you want to ensure no duplicates use a Set / Map whenever any entry (the HTML element ) is intersecting.

Comment: By 'div.myunit.no2' value you mean innerHTML?

Comment: I edited the question to try to explain it. Thank you :-)

Comment: you mean `event.target.className`? it will only give you back `"myunit no1"` for example

Comment: Hi @DoronBrikman. Thank you, that's what I was trying to find :-) Would it possible also to find the position within the array of 'myElements'? I can parse the contents of "myunit no1", but a solution similar to "indexOf" would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the `target` property i.e. `event.target`.